# A url redirection within a tab -React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I am currently trying to add my router to my application but I'm stuck at redirecting to a new url when I click on a tab.

I used React-Bootstrap to make this tab:

```
<div className="divide-nav">
  <div className="container">
                  <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1} id="uncontrolled-tab-example" onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
                        <Tab eventKey={1}  title="Blabla"></Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey={2}  title="Home" ></Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey={3}  title="Blabla" ></Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey={4}  title="Blabla" ></Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey={5}  title="Blabla" ></Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey={6}  title="Blabla" ></Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey={7}  title="Blabla" ></Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey={8}  title="Blabla" ></Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey={9}  title="Blabla" ></Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey={10} title="Blabla" ></Tab>                            
                    </Tabs>


  </div>
</div>
```

Now what I'm trying to do is when I click on let's say "Home" it redirects me to another url of my application (let's say "/Home" ).
I know there's a way with ***< Link to="/Home">Home< /Link>*** but I can't seem to add it in my < Tab>.

I also tried adding a handleSelect() method that receives the selectedKey and does an action:

```
handleSelect(selectedKey) {
 switch(selectedKey) {
    case 1 :
        location.reload();
    break;
    case 2 :
        //redirect url to =>('/Home')
    break;
 }
},
```

I received the selectedKey and could reload but I don't know how to go to another URL in a method.

*My app is local so everything is client side.

Thank you

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? react-router-redux: 4.0.8

Comment: check this, you to change the route: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/v3/docs/GettingStarted.md#navigation, check the doc also: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

Comment: Oh never thought about using history.
Alright I'll give it a try and comment back. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Pass your route as to the `eventKey` and then in **`handleSelect`**, change your route through `history.push` method

```
 handleSelect(route) {
    // Get your route name from params and pass it to history.push()
    this.props.history.push(route)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="divide-nav">
        <div className="container">
          <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1} id="uncontrolled-tab-example"  
             onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}>

            // Here eventKey will hold the route name
            <Tab eventKey={'/link1'} title="Link 1"></Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={'/link2'} title="Link 2"></Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={'link3'} title="Link 3" ></Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

If you wanna keep your eventKeys as an integer then put `switch cases` in `handleSelect`

```
  handleSelect(eventKey) {
    let route;
    // Switch cases based on eventKeys
    switch (eventKey) {
      case 1:
        route = 'link1';
        break;
      case 2:
        route = 'link2';
        break;
      case 3:
        route = 'link3';
        break;
      default:
        route = '/';
    }
    this.props.history.push(route)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="divide-nav">
        <div className="container">
          <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1} id="uncontrolled-tab-example" 
            onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)}>
            <Tab eventKey={1} title="Link 1"></Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={2} title="Link 2"></Tab>
            <Tab eventKey={3} title="Link 3" ></Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: history.push re-rendering my entire component